# Initialize multiple columns in a dataframe using mutiple operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to initialize multiple columns in pandas df using apply function.
I have a dataframe df as :

```
A
dog
cat12
rat_1 wow
```

what I want is

```
A          length   alphabet   digit
dog        3        3          0
cat12      5        3          2
rat_1 wow  9        6          1
```

This is the code I am trying:

```
def calculate(x):
    a, l, d = 0, 0, 0
    for i in x:
        if i.isalpha():
            a += 1
        elif i.isnum():
            d += 1
        l += 1
    return l, a, d

df.loc[:, ['length', 'alphabet', 'digit']] = df['A'].apply(calculate)
```

This is not working since this format works only for a single column. I need a similar format so that I can add parameters just by adding them in calculate function. This won't increase the number of iterations over the string.

I am using python3 and pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and [`Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) in a function that returns a dict of `Series`. Use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add the columns:

```
def calculate(ser):
    d= {}

    d['length'] = ser.str.len()
    d['alphabet'] = ser.str.count('[A-Za-z]')
    d['digit'] = ser.str.count('\d')

    return d

df.assign(**calculate(df.A))
```

[out]

```
           A  length  alphabet  digit
0        dog       3         3      0
1      cat12       5         3      2
2  rat_1 wow       9         6      1
```

Comment: I guess there is some issue in ser and df.A both getting called from calculate at same level

Comment: @AkashKumar your absolutely right, updated my answer

Comment: `assign` method doesn't change your df `inplace`. To actually change you'll need `df = df.assign(**calculate(df.A))`